# Probability with Martingales exercise 2.3 b.) Showing that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha = \varnothing$

Tags: probability-theory

This is the exercise 2.3 b.) in Probability with Martingales by Williams, (pp. 25). The task is to show that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha = \varnothing$, where $A$ is the set of all maps $\alpha:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha(1) < \alpha(2) < \dots$, and
$F_\alpha = \left\{\omega\in \Omega: \frac{\#(k \leq n: \omega_{\alpha(k)} = H)}{n}\to \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ where $\omega$ is $\Omega$ is the set of all outcomes of coin tosses, i.e. each $\omega \in \Omega$ is a sequence of $\{H, T\}$.

The given hint is that: *For any given $\omega$, find $\alpha \dots$ .*, and I have to say that I'm a bit puzzled on how to continue the proof.

Would it work to fix some $\alpha_1$ for which $\alpha_1(k) = 1 + 2k, k \in \mathbb{N}$? Then the only sequences $\omega$ which belong to $F_{\alpha_1}$ are those whose relative frequency of heads in every other index tends to $\frac{1}{2}$. As $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha$ is the intersection over all possible $\alpha$s, it follows that the set $F_{\alpha_2}$ also belongs to the intersection with $\alpha_2(k) = 2k$. Then perhaps we can conclude that the only common sequence $\omega$ for $F_{\alpha_1}$ and $F_{\alpha_2}$ is $\omega = (H, H, \dots)$, but this doesn't belong to the set of $F_{\alpha_3}$ with $\alpha_3(k) = k$.

Could we conclude the proof with the reasoning above, or does it have major holes in it?

Comment: To be honest, I have not understood your reasoning. However, I would follow the hint to fix an $\omega$ first; then think how this sequence can be built from heads and tails (looking at infinity); finally build a specific $\alpha$ such that $\omega \notin F_{\alpha}$